# UICollectionView collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: not response correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a class called MyView inherits from UIView, add a UICollectionView in it. But when I present a new VC which contains  MyView. But `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, did not response, except when long pressed the cell then released the finger, this method would be called.

```
class MyView: UIView {
addSubview(collectionView) // delegate and datasource are both set
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//only long press the cell and release the finger this method would be called
    }
}

 class VC {
 view.addSubview(MyView instance)
}

class rootVC {
    present Or push to VC
}
```

This is so wired.

Comment: Maybe you have a gesture? Gesture can do not miss clicking on the cell

Comment: @AlexeyKudlay thanks. I’ve found it but the gesture did not added in MyView, how this problem occurred? Can any method solve this?

Comment: can it help https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer?changes=_7

Comment: did you check whether delegate is connected or set to  MyView.

Comment: @AlexeyKudlay hummm.  I’ve already remove that gesturethanks.

Comment: @Gyanendra yes this method can be triggered.